# ThreeJS: Add Two Materials on an Mesh Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, webgl

In ThreeJS, it is possible to add more than one material to an [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Object3#api/en/core/Object3D)/Mesh according to its [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=Mesh#api/en/objects/Mesh). We can use a single `Material` or use an array of `Material`:

*Mesh typescript file class declaration and contructor (from ThreeJS src code):*

```js
export class Mesh<
    TGeometry extends BufferGeometry = BufferGeometry,
    TMaterial extends Material | Material[] = Material | Material[] // ### Here: Material[] ###
> extends Object3D {
    constructor(geometry?: TGeometry, material?: TMaterial);
```

---

Here is my problem which I can't seem to be able to solve...
When I use a single `Material`, my `Mesh` is displayed. **However, when I use two materials as an array, my `Mesh` won't display. I also don't have any error print out in the console when rendering the scene.**

My ultimate goal here is to be able to have to separate materials for the inner and the outer part of my object.
[image: Representation of my object (using only one material)]

---

*Here is my code:*

```js
export function init(radius: number = 18.0, innerColor: number = 0xFFFFFF, outerColor: number = 0x444444) {
    var obj = new Object3D();
    loader.load(
        objPath, 
        function(object){
            obj = object;
            const mesh = obj.children[0] as Mesh;
            // WORKING:
            mesh.material = new MeshPhongMaterial({color: outerColor});
            // NOT WORKING: Using two materials
            // mesh.material = new Array<Material>(new MeshPhongMaterial({color: outerColor}), new MeshPhongMaterial({color:innerColor}));
            mesh.scale.setLength(radius)
            scene.add(mesh);
        },
        function (error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    );
}
```

---

###### Why can't I manage to see my object when using two materials ?

I known there was the `MeshFaceMaterial` in previous version and the material array acceptance of the contructor is supposed to be a replacement for that in some sens.

---

> ThreeJS version: `r128`

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: To have two materials on one mesh, mesh's geometry has to have two [groups](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=bufferge#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups). Another option is to modify the material and check, if dot-product of normalized position and normal is less than 0, then use `innerColor`, otherwise `outerColor`.

Comment: Another alternative is to have two of the same mesh (they can share geometry), where one's material is set to `THREE.FrontSide` and the other mesh's material is set to `THREE.BackSide`. This _might_ cause z-fighting though, so you may also need to apply a `polygonOffset` to one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to clone your mesh and assign two separate materials, one for the inside, another for the outside:

```js
const meshOuter = obj.children[0] as THREE.Mesh;
const meshInner = meshOuter.clone();

// Outer mesh shows front side
meshOuter.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: outerColor,
    side: THREE.FrontSide
});
// Inner mesh shows back side
meshInner.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: innerColor,
    side: THREE.BackSide
});

// Scale inner mesh down just a bit to avoid z-fighting
meshInner.scale.multiplyScalar(0.99);
```